# NodeJS server Write response and start a file download

Tags: node.js, response

I'm creating a simple file conversion tool for a in-company service.

I'd created a http server where any user is able to upload a file through a form and them the server responds the request with the converted file download.

I Would like to write the conversion summary on the screen and them start the download. not just start the file download.

My code is:

```
createServer(function(req, res) {
    var form = new IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        var path = files.filetoupload.path;
        var result = dataConverter.parse(path); // File data conversion

        res.writeHead(200);
        res.write(result.summary);

        res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/force-download", "Content-disposition": "attachment; filename=outputfile.csv" });
        res.write(result.data);

        res.end();

    });
```

but i'm getting the fallowing response

> ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING

How can I write those two responses to the user?

Comment: By loading a page, then starting downloading the file from that page via script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible without some client Javascript or something like this. 
The content should be a file or write to the "page".

Te best solution was to create a temporary file to download and them send response to the page.